# How to create HeatMap from Pandas dataframe with annotated values in percentage format and divisions between each cell?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I need to create a heatmap from a pandas dataframe using plotly which will show annotated percentage values with '%' symbol. There would also be divisions between each cell in the heatmap.

| Day | Time | PizzaConsumptionFraction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1st March | 00:00:00 | 0.7 |
| 1st March | 01:00:00 | 0.6 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1st March | 23:00:00 | 0.6 |
| 2nd March | 00:00:00 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2nd March | 23:00:00 | 0.8 |

1. How can I create a heatMap from the above data using plotly.
   I can create heatmaps from pivot tables as shown below but not dataframes -

```
 kptable1 = kdf.pivot_table(index='bowling_team', columns='over', values='batsman', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0) / len(delivery)
        line_fig = px.imshow(kptable1, text_auto=".2%", aspect="equal")
```

2. I need to show annotated values with % symbol. In plotly express that is done using -

```
px.imshow(kptable1, text_auto=".3%", aspect="equal")
```

But how to make divisions between each cell in plotly express?

3. If I use plotly graph_objects to make divisions between cells in heatmap by setting xgap=4, ygap=4 then how to annotate the values in percentage format in plotly graph_objects.

I need to satisfy all the conditions and use either plotly express or plotly graph_objects.

Added -

Example code to show usage of xgap and ygap to show demarcation of some king between each cell in heatmap -

```
data = [go.Heatmap(
  z = events,
  y = days,
  x = hours,
  xgap = 5,
  ygap = 5,
  colorscale = 'Viridis'
)]

layout = go.Layout(
  title = 'Events per weekday &amp; time of day',
  xaxis = dict(
    tickmode = 'linear'
  )
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
```

Comment: In you dataframe, which column do you want to be the `index` and which one to be the `columns` when you `pivot`?? And what are the divisions between each cells that you want to do?

Comment: Index=Day. Columns=Time. Values=PizzaConsumptionFraction. Between each cell in the heatmap there should be a thin black border line just for better clarity of the image.

Comment: Can you use both `plotly express` and `graph_objects`?

Comment: I have to generate only 1 heatmap. It cant be like - I am using plotly express to generate 1 heatmap and graph_objects to generate another. Is it possible to combine plotly express and graph_objects together to generate 1 heatmap only?

Comment: I have a solution using both of them but I can't find how to add the cells' borders. Tell me if you are interested.

Comment: Yes please. But applying the cell borders or showing any clear demarcation between each cell is also a necessity for better clarity. As mentioned, using plotly graph_objects I can demarcate the cells using xgap, ygap but cant annotate them with percentage values. Using plotly express I can annotate but cant set set cell borders. But I am interested to see your solution.

Comment: Can you please provide in your question the way that you use the `xgap` and `ygap` using `plotly` so as to include it in my final answer? And I will post it this day later.

Comment: Added the usage of xgap ygap.

Comment: Gaps between cells are generated by updating the gap settings for the figs created by express. `fig = px.imshow(kptable1, text_auto=".3%", aspect="equal");fig.update_traces(xgap=5, ygap=5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these solve your problem.

### Solution #1

Here we use both libraries.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame([["1st March", "00:00:00" ,0.77],
                   ["1st March", "01:00:00", 0.6],
                   ["1st March","23:00:00",0.6], 
                   ["2nd March","00:00:00",1],
                   ["2nd March","01:00:00",0.4],
                   ["2nd March","23:00:00",0.8]],
                  columns=["Day", "Time", "PCF"])

df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='PCF', index='Day', columns=['Time'], sort=False).fillna(0)
# df = df.pivot(index='Day', columns='Time')['PCF'].fillna(0)

fig = px.imshow(df, x=df.columns, y=df.index, text_auto=True)
fig = go.Figure(data=fig.data, layout=fig.layout)
fig = fig.update_traces(text=df.applymap(lambda x: x).values, texttemplate="%{text}%", hovertemplate=None, xgap=5, ygap=5)
fig.show()
```

In the solution above, `df.pivot()` (*it is commented*) sorts the dataframe automatically based on *Day* and it has no parameter to set it to **false** (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)). You can use `pd.pivot_table()` instead and set sorting to **false**.

Output 1:
[image: Heatmap 1]

### Solution #2

An alternative, if you want to use only the `graph_objects` library.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Some test data
df = pd.DataFrame([["1st March", "00:00:00" ,0.77],
                   ["1st March", "01:00:00", 0.6],
                   ["1st March","23:00:00",0.6], 
                   ["2nd March","00:00:00",1],
                   ["2nd March","01:00:00",0.4],
                   ["2nd March","23:00:00",0.8]],
                  columns=["Day", "Time", "PCF"])


data = [go.Heatmap(
  z = df["PCF"],
  y = df["Day"],
  x = df["Time"],
  xgap = 5,
  ygap = 5,
  colorscale = 'Viridis'
)]

layout = go.Layout(
  title = 'Events per weekday &amp; time of day',
  xaxis = dict(
    tickmode = 'linear'
  )
)

# Use pd.pivot_table() if you don't want to sort
df = df.pivot(index='Day', columns='Time')['PCF'].fillna(0)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig = fig.update_traces(text=df.applymap(lambda x: x).values, texttemplate="%{text}%", hovertemplate=None)
fig.show()
```

Output 2:
[image: Heatmap 2]

### UPDATED - Solution using *only* `plotly.express`

And the Dataframe is not sorted, like you asked. The output heatmap proves that.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame([["1st March", "00:00:00" ,0.77],
                   ["1st March", "01:00:00", 0.6],
                   ["10th March","23:00:00",0.6], 
                   ["11th March","00:00:00",1],
                   ["2nd March","01:00:00",0.4],
                   ["22th March","23:00:00",0.8]],
                  columns=["Day", "Time", "PCF"])

df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='PCF', index='Day', columns=['Time'], sort=False).fillna(0)
fig = px.imshow(df, x=df.columns, y=df.index, text_auto=True, title="Events per weekday &amp; time of day")
fig = fig.update_traces(text=df.applymap(lambda x: x).values, texttemplate="%{text}%", hovertemplate=None, xgap=5, ygap=5)
fig.show()
```

Output 3:
[image: Heatmap 3]

Comment: Thanks. I am following the first solution. However on plotting the heatmap for entire one month, the indexes are coming like - 1st March, 10thMarch, 11thMarch, 2nd March instead of 1st March, 2nd March....10th March as present in the dataset.   Using pivot_table , I know this issue can be solved like - pd.pivot_table(data,values="zz",index="yy",columns="xx",sort=False,aggfunc=sum). But how to solve this issue in df.pivot()? I need to preserve the order day wise as present in original dataset.

Comment: It seems from the docs that `df.pivot()` has no `sort` parameter. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: I added the solution with `pd.pivot_table`.

Comment: @MVKXXX Is my solution OK? Have you checked it after the update?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The only thing is I need to append a "%" sign and then display the values. I can use either plotly express or graph_objects but not both at the same time (like you have done in Solution 1). I am using plotly express. With that if I do px.imshow(heatmap,text_auto=".1%"), then it multiplies the values by 100 and then appends %. But I just want to append % only. Can you kindly tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: @MVKXXX will you accept the answer as correct? :)